# Ubuntu One in Fedora

Tags: fedora, cloud

I have an Ubuntu One account and want to be able to sync it to a folder in Fedora. Is this possible and what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all this time, I finally found my answer. [Maxiberta's Blog](http://www.maxiberta.com.ar/blog/ubuntuone-packages-fedora) has concise instructions on installing a Fadora friendly package for Ubuntu One.

Paraphrased:

```
su
wget http://www.maxiberta.com.ar/repo/fedora-ubuntuone.repo 
mv fedora-ubuntuone.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
yum install ubuntuone-client
u1sdtool --connect
```

For more info, go to http://www.maxiberta.com.ar/blog/ubuntuone-packages-fedora

Answer (score 1):

It is possible — install the ubuntu one client and you should be all set. If it still isn't in the official repositories, you can follow the older instructions here (will not get you the latest!): http://www.pacificsimplicity.ca/blog/ubuntu-one-fedora-16-howto

Comment: I followed the link, but looks like most of the package links on it are now dead.

Comment: where they're dead, delete them up and including to "trunk" (from the end) and pick the latest release's download.

Comment: Managed to find the latest packages and follow the tutorial and after fixing several spelling mistakes throughout, fail to successfully install Ubuntu One. I got several Python errors I think i managed to fix, but the final step of launching the app fails.

Comment: `[andrew@Andy-PC ~]$ /usr/libexec/ubuntuone-syncdaemon --debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/libexec/ubuntuone-syncdaemon", line 49, in <module>
    from ubuntuone.platform import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone/platform/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from dirspec.utils import user_home
ImportError: No module named dirspec.utils
[andrew@Andy-PC ~]$`

Comment: install python-dirspec

Comment: Yum says´Package not available´. Google gives me lots of Ubuntu results and .deb packages but no RPM ones.

Comment: search for it with yum, maybe it's just dirspec or python2-dirspec as some trivial googling suggests. Otherwise install the deb or the arch package (just a tar extract away).

Comment: I think I installed Debian Dirspec ok. Now I get no responce when I try to launch UbuntuOne (terminal seems to hang)

Comment: maybe it's waiting for input, try ctrl-d (I have no idea how this app works).